Meaning of "endorsement" codes on flight booking?
I've booked a flight with British Airways and have received a confirmation email with details of the booking.
In the information provided, it says:
"Endorsements: Pax nonref/hbo -z0h"
I've searched for this code, but the most I found was the airline's terms and conditions of travel with no explanation for these "endorsement" codes.
"nonref" most likely means "non-refundable", but what about the other parts?


pax = passenger
nonref = non-refundable
hbo = Hand Baggage Only


Where can one find the rest of the list? This fulfills the exact needs of OP, but does not answer the core question.
